# Understanding basic DOM chaining

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm getting started with JavaScript and the DOM, trying to purposely stay away from jQuery and the like, at least for a little while. With that in mind, tutorials generally provide an example such as this:

```
h = document.createElement("h1");
t = document.createTextNode("Hello.");
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);
```

In an attempt to streamline this and avoid variables, I successfully chained the following:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello."));
```

While this works, I tried to shorten the following prepend operation:

```
h = document.createElement("h1");
t = document.createTextNode("Put this on top.");
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.insertBefore(h,document.body.firstChild);
```

with the following:

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("h1")).appendChild(document.createTextNode("Put this on top."),document.body.firstChild);
```

But this time it didn't work as desired: the text is placed at the very end of the BODY element, obtaining an append instead of a prepend.

I imagine the successful first case is just a fluke, but I can't see what's wrong with this chaining practice.

Comment: You've closed your `insertBefore()` parens after the `createElement()`. So the chain seems to have continued with the `appendChild()` method. Which surprises me, I would've expected an error.

Comment: Though chaining like this is interesting as a way to understand how these methods work, the result is harder to read. Having to scroll right to see the whole statement is kind of annoying, but you can put a line break before `.appendChild()` or after the opening parens from one or more methods...

Comment: Use a minifying tool to "streamline and avoid variables" - you're just making your code harder to read, maintain, and extend.

Comment: You're right, David... Sorry for the confusion. I now expect an error too! Thanks to all for the feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have parenthesis in the wrong places. Your line:

```
document.body.insertBefore( document.createElement("h1") )
.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Put this on top."), document.body.firstChild );
```

How it should be:

```
document.body.insertBefore(
    document.createElement("h1").appendChild(
        document.createTextNode("Put this on top.")), document.body.firstChild);
```

Now you understand why this is generally a bad idea to merge all in one line.

Ok, this fixed line will not give you exact behavior of your code 'with variables'. This is because .appendChild returns the child DOM element (`<INPUT>` in your case), not the parent (`<H1>` in your case). But you want so that all `<H1>` DOM element was added at the beginning of document. To achieve this in one line you need to use .parentNode property:

```
document.body.insertBefore(
    document.createElement("h1").appendChild(
        document.createTextNode("Put this on top.")).parentNode, document.body.firstChild)
```

Guys, please do not use such code, this is just for educational purposes)))

Comment: Note that `.appendChild()` returns the _child_ element, so just switching around the parentheses won't solve the problem.

Comment: this is not a "problem")) I have just showed him his error in parenthesis. All other code here is to "avoid variables", which is pointless at least

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I realize it is not recommended to do this, but I wanted to see it work, and I had completely missed the need to refer to parentNode. Using bare JS, how do you go about something as simple as this in practice?